# Can you represent function in an array of char?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I learned that function and data have no intrinsic difference. Can you initialize an array of char, and cast the char pointer to a function pointer, and use it as a function. I do not have enough knowledge to make it real because I do not know the way that compiler uses to represent the function instruction inside a block of memory. But I believe that there are people in this site who have adequate expertise to achieve it. : )

```
char* a = "blahbleeblue";//gibberish to other people
auto func = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()> a;
func();//due to careful planning, do what ever you ask
```

Comment: "But I believe that there are people in this site who have adequate expertise to achieve it" - The better of those people have enough expertise **not** to do this.

Comment: You're welcome to try.  You won't get very far.

Comment: `Possible` and `useful` are 2 very different things ...

Comment: A pointer is a bunch of bits that contain an address.  At that address is the data or function of interest.  Not only is a function in *very* cryptic form, it is generally in a special part of memory, where "executables" reside.  If you attempt to "execute" ordinary data you will, on most boxes, get a memory protection exception.

Comment: If your char array contains a valid shared/dynamic library, you can write it to a temporary location and use platform specific functions to load the library, then locate the function. But this is very dangerous, especially if the char array is from the network.

Comment: Try using `std::map<std::string, /* function pointer */`.  You are creating an *association* between strings and pointers to functions.  Before you do this ask yourself "why do i *need* this functionality?"

Answer (score 1):

"I learned that function and data have no intrinsic difference."

In some languages, typically interpreted ones, this is the case. Like javascript, lisp etc.

In c this is not the case. Data and code are quite different things (I know they are bits stored in memory, buts not really relevant) and most operating systems go to great efforts to prevent you doing what you are doing things that mix them up (it looks like bugs or hacking).

When you do the CS500 level courses you may find places where code rewrites itself on the fly, effectively treating its code as data, but this is rare

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an X-Y problem.
I'll assume you want to execute a function based on some string.

**Function Pointers and Maps**
This technique only works if the function signatures are the same:

```
// Define a synonym for a function pointer that returns nothing  
// and has a single integer argument.
typedef void (*Function_Pointer(int argument));

// Some declarations:  
void Process_Apple(int a);
void Process_Pineapple(int b);
void Process_Carrot(int c);

// Initialize the map
typedef std::map<std::string, Function_Pointer> Function_Dictionary;
Function_Dictionary func_table;
func_table["apple"] = Process_Apple;
func_table["pineapple"] = Process_Pineapple;
func_table["carrot"] = Process_Carrot;

// You can use 'find' to find the associated function
Function_Dictionary::iterator iter;
std::string function_name = "apple";
iter = func_table.find(function_name);
if (iter != func_table.end())
{
  Function_Ptr f = iter->second;
  // Execute the function
  f(27);
}
```

**Table Lookup**
You could also create a table and use a lookup.

```
struct Func_Assoc
{
  char * name;
  Function_Ptr f;
};
Func_Association lookup_table[] =
{
  {"apple", Process_Apple},
  {"pineapple", Process_Pineapple},
  //...
};
static const table_size =
  sizeof(lookup_table) / sizeof(lookup_table[0]);
```

Search the `lookup_table` for the name, then deference the associated function pointer.  A nice advantage to this scheme is that the data is constant and read-only and can be accessed by your program without any run-time initialization.

See also:  Factory Design Pattern, Reflection

Answer (score -1):

It can indeed be done. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void say_hello(void) {
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}

using fptr = std::function<void(void)>; 

int main() {
    char *cptr = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&say_hello);
    fptr func = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(void)>(cptr);
    
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Hello world
```

http://ideone.com/uFUKcw

---

If you want to build up your own string which will somehow evaluate to a function pointer, **this is not possible because**:

1. The pointer will have to point to a user defined constant i.e. the string you decide to use.
2. This constant has to live at some memory address which is the same memory address that the pointer is pointing to...can you see the problem?

Now if you also decide that this pointer has to somehow evaluate to a function, then one choice is immediately not possible because

*A pointer cannot (should not) point to two different things at once. If your pointer is pointing to a static string (see the second point above), it should not also at the same time point to a function address*.
The only other choice you have requires two other things

1. You are programming at a very low level (kernel pretty much)
2. You know exactly where your data segment begins

#### From here on is highly theoretical

*At this point, I'm not even sure how well this will work because I've only seen something remotely close in OS code. When the OS boots up, it needs to setup a chunk of memory in order to initialize a few things (determine the total memory available, setup page tables, start file system, etc). This chunk it allocates has a known physical address and using this, **the init code for the boot process can place functions where it chooses**.*

Now, say you had your function resident at memory address `0x1EETC0DE`, you can use a normal unsigned integer to hold this value.

```
unsigned secret_weapon = 0x1EETC0DE;
```

When the time is right, you can simply create this integer and cast it's value to a function pointer, and...well you decide from here on.

Comment: To be fair, this doesn't prove much, but at least it attempts to answer an interesting question instead of dismissing OP.

Comment: thats not really the same thing. Thats a declared function compiled into an executable code segment already, you are simply manipulating a pointer to it

Comment: @MillieSmith What was it supposed to prove?

Comment: @pm100 Can you please explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Well it doesn't solve creating a function yourself  by building an array of characters that contain machine code and reside in executable memory and can jump back to the old EIP (or elsewhere) when done executing. It does show that you can cast back and forth, which is part of the battle.

Comment: @MillieSmith Ohh. Well that should be interesting